# Why should my flask application have the database and database repository in the parent directory of the application?

Tags: python, flask

Reading through a lot of articles on how to structure a Flask application many people do say to do so as such:

```
~/AppName
    |-- run.py                    # simple run script to start app
    |-- config.py                 # configuration info for app
    |-- app.db                    # actual database blob for app
    |-- /db_repository            # for storing database migration data
    |__ /env                      # Virtual Environment
    |__ /app                      # Application Module
         |-- __init__.py          # runs when you import app from ../run.py
         |-- /module_one          # Submodule
             |-- __init__.py      
             |-- controllers.py
             |-- models.py                
         |__ /templates
             |__ /module_one
                 |-- hello.html
         |__ /static              # Static folder for app
         |__ ..
         |__ .
    |__ ..
    |__ .
```

Why do people recommend this instead of having `app.db`,`db_repository`, and `config.py` inside the `app` directory. It seems more consistent that the applications database would be in the same level, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, there is no such thing as one globally accepted way of structuring Flask projects. Flask is called a *micro*-framework partly because it doesn't do scaffolding.

Now, as you noticed, some patterns stand out.

From my experience, the idea behind the pattern you describe is to keep all your application codebase in a single directory so that your IDE can handle it easily, and all the file you may want to access quickly at the root of the repository so that you can use them from command line without having to type long path lines.